# Catch all endpoint with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking to capture all requests made that match a particular format (ie a `regex` match) to route through to a single endpoint in my .NET Core 3.0 application.

For example, I'm looking to match a URL that is formatted as:

`https://localhost:5001/test/status/1234567899999`

Where `/test/` and the `int` ID can be any degree of characters, hence the regex.

[The regex works fine, as seen here.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2F%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5D%2B%29%2Fstatus%2F%5Cd%2B&i=%2Ftest%2Fstatus%2F1234567899999)

[I've taken a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249807/asp-net-core-how-to-check-the-request-for-a-match-with-a-regular-expression) and wrote the following:

```
        app.MapWhen(context => 
            Regex.IsMatch(context.Request.Path, @"/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/status/\d+"),
            test => test.UseMvc(routes => 
                                    routes.MapRoute(name: "Tweet", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Test}")));
```

Which captured *every* request, regardless of matching the Regex.

I've also tried pattern matching inside a `Route` attribute as such:

```
    [HttpGet, Route(@"{path:regex(/([[a-zA-Z0-9_]]+)/status/d+)}")]
    public IActionResult Test([FromRoute] string path)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;

        return Ok(s);
    }
```

This captured no requests, but I can see in the debug console that the requests were piped through my application fine. They just never hit a defined endpoint.

Note the double `[[ ]]` are used for parsing inside the route as directed by .NET Core.

Is there a better way of matching a pattern via the `request.Path` and rerouting the request to a controller endpoint?

Comment: I haven't used regex routing rules myself, but reading the documentation suggests that should be ```Route(@"{path:regex(^[[a-zA-Z0-9]]+$)}/...")```. Since each route parameter is tested against each constraint independently, the regex must include ^$ to compare the whole string.

Comment: Can you use any other char instead of `/`? i.e `@"/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/status/\d+")` -> `@"/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)--status--\d+")` then you can manually convert all `--` to `/` in code.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use [Custom Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints).

Step-1: Create a route constraint by implementing `IRouteConstraint`.

```
public class RegexConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(httpContext.Request.Path, "\\w+[-]{2}status[-]{2}\\d+");
    }
}
```

Step-2: Register your constraint `Startup.cs` -> `ConfigureServices` method like

```
services.AddRouting(options => { options.ConstraintMap.Add("regexRouter", typeof(RegexConstraint)); });
```

Step-3: Use your custom route constraint like below

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("test/index/{path:regexRouter}")]
    public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] string path)
    {
        return Ok(path);
    }

    [HttpGet("test/get/{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }
}
```

Now if you run your application and type in

1--> `https://localhost:5001/test/index/longinitial--status--122` output 'longinitial--status--122'

2--> `https://localhost:5001/test/get/123` output `123`

To build the path you can simply replace `--` with `/` inside your `Index` action.

```
path = path.Replace("--", "/");
```

I hope this helps.